# CakePHP deleteAll throws PDOException

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo

I am working with CakePHP 2.10, in a Shell file I have the following operation:

```php
$this->loadModel('WorklistsClient');
$this->WorklistsClient->deleteAll(array('WorklistsClient.client_id' => $client_id), false);
```

Sometimes this perfectly runs, and some other times I receive the error:

```
Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null
#0 /composer_modules/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(468): DboSource->_execute()
#1 /composer_modules/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php(459): DboSource->execute()
#2 /composer_modules/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2848): Mysql->delete()
#3 /api/Console/Command/WorklistsShell.php(242): Model->deleteAll()
```

Needles to say this stop the execution.

I have made sure $client_id exists when it fails, the model has been loaded and there are not reletaded records to delete.

I have read the code from DboSource.php and the call to prepare() seems to be performed on `$this->__connection` which according to documentation refers `to the physical connection of this DataSource`

I've already tried to initialize the model on the Shell class property `$uses` and even use `Class::registry()` instead of `loadModel()` but keep getting the error sometimes.

Any idea of what can be causing this issue?

Comment: Any chance that  you're using persistent connections and the persistence sometimes happens to be timing out around this execution?

Comment: @GregSchmidt  Thank you, this help me to better debug the problem. It seems that the connection was not persistent in my shells and after finishing any other transaction went back to sleep. I added `$this->Model->getDataSource()->reconnect()` before my operation and it's been working perfectly.